# React Bootstrap in JSX file in Meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-bootstrap

I have installed React Bootstrap package in my meteor app.

https://atmospherejs.com/universe/react-bootstrap

On that page it says that:

> This package additionally export ReactBootstrap as a global, so you
>   can write inside any .jsx file

It then gives an example.

```
let { Button } = ReactBootstrap;

<Button /> // React component
or

<ReactBootstrap.Button /> // React component
```

However, when I do:

```
render(){


        return (
                <div>

                    <ReactBootstrap.Button/>

                </div>
            );
    }
```

inside my render() function for React in Meteor I get the following error:

> universe_react-bootstrap.js?hash=85ba81631c5fee5b5e0bceb7d1dc34847f2f2e89:14811
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of
>   undefined
>       at Constructor (universe_react-bootstrap.js?hash=85ba81631c5fee5b5e0bceb7d1dc34847f2f2e89:14811)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (ReactCompositeComponent.js:291)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:259)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:178)
>       at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:49)
>       at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:242)
>       at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:704)
>       at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:529)
>       at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:49)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:367)

But if I do:

```
render(){
   console.log(ReactBootstrap)
}
```

I get confirmation that that global variable exists....

How do I use it ReactBootstrap within the div tags???

This is the whole code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


// App component - represents the whole app
export default class App extends Component {



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Testing</h1>
        <ReactBootstrap.Button /> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is GitHub link:
https://github.com/blissGitHub/TestingReactBootstrapWithMeteor.git

Comment: Could you show the whole code this `render()` function belongs to?

Comment: Yes please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems like in `universe:react-bootstrap` package. It's too old and seems like not maintained anymore. It uses outdated version of `react-boostrap`: `0.24.2`, while its current one is `0.31.3` (released just 3 weeks ago).

So, it seems like we should get rid of it:

```
meteor remove universe:react-bootstrap
meteor add twbs:bootstrap
meteor npm i --save react-bootstrap
```

And slightly modify your code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';

// App component - represents the whole app
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Testing</h1>
        <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="success">Click Me</ReactBootstrap.Button> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Of course, you can use it like this:

```js
import ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';
const { Button } = ReactBootstrap;
...
<Button bsStyle="...">...</Button>
```

or like this:

```js
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
...
<Button bsStyle="...">...</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the [docs](https://atmospherejs.com/universe/react-bootstrap) for the package, I believe you can do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'bootstrap';


// App component - represents the whole app
export default class App extends Component {



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Testing</h1>
        <Button /> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```